# Laser cooling for an electron

Tags: electrons, laser-interaction

In [laser cooling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling), atoms can be slowed down by momentum transfer.

> Laser cooling relies on the change in momentum when an object, such as an atom, absorbs and re-emits a photon (a particle of light).

There was even a Nobel Prize for this.

> The 1997 Nobel Prize in Physics was awarded to Claude Cohen-Tannoudji, Steven Chu, and William Daniel Phillips "for development of methods to cool and trap atoms with laser light".

Can you also manipulate a single electron (or an electron cloud) using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an *optical molasses* the atom absorbs the photon from a well defined direction and then it reemits it in a random direction. Thus, during the absorption we can decelerate the atom, but during the emission we can not control whether the atom is accelerated or decelerated. Thus, on average the emission has no effect except of bringing the atom back to its ground state.

As the electron is a fundamental particle, it does not possess an internal level structure. Therefore, it can not absorb the photon. Therefore, the closes analog I can think of is *Compton scattering*, which is an inelastic scattering process between a single photon and a single electron.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the Compton scattering processes.